# How to tell the app a new contact is added or deleted or modified in address book and its details in android

Tags: android

Is there any listener when contact is added or deleted or modified in Address book?

I want to know which contact is added or deleted or modified.

**Edit:**

With below comment onChange() is being called. But my problem is how to know the effected contact and its details. I mean which contact is modified ?

Please some one help me on this. Thank you

Comment: This has already been answered here. [Contact changes][1]
Thanks


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401280/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-contact-database

Comment: @user1242340 thank you for the link. It is solved. But how to know which contact is effected ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service and listen for ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21650621/2922126) it may help.

Comment: But how to know which contact is effected ? I mean contact details required after modification.

Comment: ContactsContract.RawContacts.VERSION & CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP may be useful to store and compare if any differences.