# BroadcastReceiver to listen when a contact added or deleted from favorite/stared

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

Is there a way to listen/handle at the time when a contact is added/deleted from favorite/starred contact list.

I have checked for [`onChange()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650621/how-to-listen-contact-inserted-updated-deleted-in-address-book). But its not handling the Favorite/Starred settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default contact observer .. I hope its helpful for you

```
public class MyCOntentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public MyCOntentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            final int currentCount = getContactCount();

            // Get count from your sqlite database
            int mContactCount = getContactOWNCount();

            if (currentCount < mContactCount) {
                // DELETE HAPPEN.
                Log.e("Status", "Deletion");
                //contactDBOperaion.SyncContacts(1);
            } else if (currentCount == mContactCount) {
                // UPDATE HAPPEN.
                //  contactDBOperaion.SyncContacts(0);
            } else {
                // INSERT HAPPEN.
                Log.e("Status", "Insertion");
                // contactDBOperaion.SyncContacts(2);
            }
            Log.e("", "~~~~~~" + selfChange);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```