# How does whatsapp detects my newly added number using same app very quickly?

Tags: java, android, synchronization, whatsapp

How does Whatsapp detects any newly added number using the app very quickly, and shows an icon in contact details immediately. I am not asking how to do it but my question is how to do it as fast as whatsapp does ?

Comment: you can set `ContentObserver` to receive listener on contact change, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996921/how-do-i-make-my-android-contentobserver-for-contactscontract-detect-a-added-up for more info

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i am not asking how i can achieve it but my question is how to so it as fast as whatsapp do you have any idea ? because i have done it but its not working so fast

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it is listening for contact changes or just checks each time it opens for any differences. (Can't comment yet so delete this if wrong)